# Como agregar una propiedad nueva a todos los objetos de un array de objetos, con valores que están en un array de strings

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

tengo un array de objetos que es el siguiente:

```
const arrayCarrito = [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Makinoi",
        especie: "Sedum"
    },
    {    
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Major",
        especie: "Echeveria"
    },
    {    
        id: 3,
        nombre: "Spiralis",
        especie: "Cactus"
    },
]
```

Y necesito agregarle una nueva propiedad (llamada cantidad) a todos estos objetos, cuyos valores están en un array de números que es el siguiente:

```
const arrayCantidades = [7,2,4];
```

De manera que cuando imprima mi array de objetos, obtenga algo como esto

```
{id: 1, nombre: 'Makinoi', especie: 'Sedum', cantidad: 7}
{id: 2, nombre: 'Major', especie: 'Echeveria', cantidad: 2}
{id: 3, nombre: 'Spiralis', especie: 'Cactus', cantidad: 4}
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme! gracias :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const arrayCarrito = [{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Makinoi",
    especie: "Sedum"
},
{    
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Major",
    especie: "Echeveria"
},
{    
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Spiralis",
    especie: "Cactus"
},
]

const arrayCantidades = [7,2,4]

const nuevoArrayCarrito = arrayCarrito.map((item, indice) => ({...item, cantidad: arrayCantidades[indice]}))

console.log(nuevoArrayCarrito)
```

Comment: Me sirvio! muchisimas gracias